# Keyboard shortcuts for GraphQL Playground

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql, graphql-playground

I am an android developer but just started to play with `GraphQL` as per new project requirements. I am trying to query in the `prisma-lab's` `graphQL-playground`.

I copied and pasted a long query which in the single line but I just want to format that in `JSON` format. Is anyone have an idea how to do that? or Anyone knows more shortcuts about this prisma-lab's graphQL-playground.

Copied Query:

```
{ userInfo(userName:"xyz"){   id  subtitle  userLastName   avatar } }
```

Formatted Query:

```
{
  userInfo(userName: "xyz") {
    id
    subtitle
    userLastName
    avatar
  }
}
```

Suggest if anyone knows how to format this query and if there is any other keyboard shortcuts available for GraphQL-Playground.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just hit the prettify button top left? [image]

Comment: Oh, Greg. Thanks a lot. Really helpful. I just started it and it was horrible to not able to format it. Do you know any more keyboard shortcuts to play with it? Then update your answer with that then it will be helpful.

Comment: I don’t actually, autocomplete and the docs take care of most anything I have ever needed.. plus the I leave my tabs open and add a new tab for new queries so that I don’t have to retune them all the time, history only holds so much but you can seemingly open infinite tabs and they cache

Comment: No worries Greg. Appreciated. Accepting your answer.